# Displaying Names on the Map using KML

Tags: kml, google-earth

I am able to display polygons, circles, etc etc, using KML.
Now i want to display only some Names using KML. Is this Possible ?

Comment: Do you mean display on Google Earth, Google Maps, or other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to suppress displaying the label of placemarks (via KML) on the map of Google Earth then you can add a [LabelStyle](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#labelstyle) to your placemarks with a 0 scale (see *sn_hide* style in example below). If you want to suppress the label name on the map until you hover over the icon then [StyleMaps](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#stylemap) are your best bet.

The first placemark in example below has its name shown in the places panel but hidden from the map using the *LabelStyle*. The second placemark #2 uses a *StyleMap* to hide the label until the user highlights or mouses over the icon in which it activates the highlight style showing the label. The third placemark #3 uses the default style that always shows the label.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
    <Document>
        <name>Hide and show labels</name>
        <Style id="sn_hide">
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>0</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id="sh_style">
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
        </Style>
        <StyleMap id="msn_hide">
            <Pair>
                <key>normal</key>
                <styleUrl>#sn_hide</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
            <Pair>
                <key>highlight</key>
                <styleUrl>#sh_style</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
        </StyleMap>

        <Placemark>
            <name>Placemark 1</name>
            <description>Label name always hidden</description>
            <styleUrl>#sn_hide</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-119.232195,36.016021</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>

        <Placemark>
            <name>Placemark 2</name>
            <description>Hover over place to show label</description>
            <styleUrl>#msn_hide</styleUrl>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-119.2324,36.0155</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>

        <Placemark>
            <name>Placemark 3</name>
            <description>Always showing</description>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>-119.232672,36.014837</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
    </Document>
</kml>
```